# Compute functional from its first variation

Tags: calculus-of-variations, entropy, optimal-transport

Adopting the philosophy that the first variation of a functional (as defined e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Functional_derivative)) is like the gradient of a function, is there a way to test whether a given function is the first variation of some functional? I am specifically interested in finding a functional $E$ such that
$$\frac{\delta E}{\delta \rho} = \log(\rho \ast \phi_\varepsilon)$$
where
$\phi_\varepsilon$ is the probability density function of the Gaussian distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\varepsilon$, and $\rho \ast \phi_\varepsilon$ denotes convolution of two real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

If it helps, I know that
$$\frac{\delta E}{\delta \rho} = \phi_\varepsilon \ast \log(\rho \ast \phi_\varepsilon)$$
for
$$E(\rho) = \int_\mathbb{R} \phi_\varepsilon \ast \rho \log(\rho\ast\phi_\varepsilon).$$

The motivation for this question is extending the entropy functional to a discrete measure $\rho$. I came across a very similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3218995/inverse-functional-derivatives-find-a-functional-whose-functional-derivative-is), and from the second answer it seems that no such functional exists. But I am not sure if I understood that answer well enough to trust my calculation.